# How do I extract more information from places nearby using google places API?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

My app only extracts name and address from the location selected from google places API. I want it to extract phone numbers as well. How do I do that? Below is my MapActivity.JAVA that enables the google places api and shows nearby places. I followed a tutorial and it only had extracted name and address, so I'm stuck now. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

**MapActivity.JAVA**

```
package com.golo.acer.mrestro4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private TextView mAttributions;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(27.690668, 85.313401), new LatLng(27.692634, 85.318969));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
        pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW);
                    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(MapActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                        | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void moveToInternalChoiceActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InternalChoiceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }

            mName.setText(name);
            mAddress.setText(address);
            mAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));

        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe helpful https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details & https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details